# Interval in $\mathbb{R}$ is path connected.

Tags: general-topology

Prove that every interval in $\mathbb{R}$ is connected by proving it was path connected.

I can prove that every interval in $\mathbb{R}$ is connected directly but this question asking to prove it is path connected and then it implies that it is connected so I do not know how to prove it. I need help. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Given two points $a<b$ in an interval $I$, the function 
$$f(t)=(1-t)a+tb$$
for $0\leq t\leq 1$ is a path in $I$ from $a$ to $b$. (By the way, this approach works for any convex subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$).

However, this question seems a bit circular to me, as the "standard" proof that path connected spaces are connected uses the fact that $[0,1]$ is connected.